# CONCAT search in columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT
  People.Name, People.Secondname
  CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname)
FROM People, Shop, Circus
WHERE CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname) != Shop.Buyer 
  AND CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname) != Circus.Watcher
```

Ok, so this is my question. There are 2 columns. I have concat'ed them and want to find list of people who havent been in Shop AND Circus. Like: I have concated full name - "Jhon Jhonson".  He havent been in circus and havent been in shop. So i want him to be shown.

Becouse I cant publish picture here, at least i can get link of table i am trying to make...  http://imm.io/1k5tJ
I hope you can decipher what I want to say.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but doing cartesian joins between 3 tables would usually be unnecessary and is definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
  People.Name, People.Secondname
  CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname)
FROM People left outer join Shop on CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname) = Shop.Buyer 
left outer join Circus on  CONCAT(People.Name," ", People.Secondname) = Circus.Watcher
where Shop.Buyer is null and  Circus.Watcher is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above of: "i would like to find whom are in Concated column, but not in the Users AND not in Participants", then this query will let you choose all tbl1 data where the user AND participant do not exist in the secondary and tertiary tables respectively.

```
select
  tbl1.name,
  tbl1.name2
from People tbl1
  left join Show1 tbl2 on tbl1.name = tbl2.user
  left join Show2 tbl3 on tbl1.name2 = tbl3.participant
where tbl2.user is null
  and tbl3.participant is null
```

I think your description of the problem is still unclear, but this is a step in the right direction.

**Update:**  Change column names based on your comments on question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it didint work for me :/ IF You have any other ideas, then be My guest :)

Comment: I did this query on the fly and did not validate.  I left off the word outer.  Looks like it is the same as the accepted response except for the the user and participant field actually is a concatenated field which I did not expect.  Glad someone got it to work for you!

Comment: Haha, Thanks for writing almost good way, its easier for others when they have some leads ^^